# Where can I download Xubuntu released wallpapers?

Tags: xubuntu, desktop-background

I know that Xubuntu has released the community wallpaper contest winners ; where can I download them?

Comment: Do you have any idea about other wallpapers?have they been released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the link of the newest won Xubuntu 14.04 wallpapers , they are **wonderful** !

[Xubuntu 14.04 Wallpapers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Xubuntu/Roadmap/Specifications/Trusty/CommunityWallpapers/Winners)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to install both the default and community wallpapers is to us the packages:

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-wallpapers xubuntu-community-wallpapers`

Here are the contents:

```
$ dpkg -L xubuntu-wallpapers 
[...]
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-wallpapers
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-wallpapers/copyright
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-wallpapers/changelog.gz
/usr/share/xfce4
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-saucy.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-quantal.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-raring.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-trusty.png
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/xubuntu-wallpaper.png

$ dpkg -L  xubuntu-community-wallpapers
[...]
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/solitude.jpg
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/balance.jpg
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/traslasierra.jpg
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/cloudbreaker.jpg
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/bubbles.jpg
/usr/share/xfce4/backdrops/justrocks.jpg
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-community-wallpapers
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-community-wallpapers/README
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-community-wallpapers/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-community-wallpapers/copyright
```

You'll also get this from the README (`/usr/share/doc/xubuntu-community-wallpapers/README`):

> For more work by Adrian Felipe Pera (traslasierra.jpg), visit
>   http://www.flickr.com/photos/afpera For more work by Gavin Ash
>   (balance.jpg, solitude.jpg), visit http://www.gavinash.com

Answer (score 0):

Here. I made this folder by collecting the default wallpapers for Xubuntu on websites. This folder may update if I find more, anyways, took me a while. `whew

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14vi0mDG9eramvqZLTwG8BcfRkAGdCRni